# How to change the color of an image in GIMP

Tags: ubuntu, gimp

If I have the image below, how do I change the black color to some other color and green to something else in [GIMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) on Linux?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See *[Changing Background Color 1](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Changing_Background_Color_1/)*. It uses the *Color to Alpha* plug-in.

But the quality of this image is as low as its complexity, and I think you should just make an new one.

Comment: thanks. I was thinking about making new one but was not able to make the damn triangle in the middle

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The described <context menu> -> *Filters* -> *Colors* -> *Colors to Alpha* item mentioned in the article (under ***Step 1***) does not appear to be available in GIMP 2.8.10.