# Change the color of an image using GIMP

Tags: gimp

I am trying to change the color of the [GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) file. How can I do this?

I couldn't do it with Hue saturation.

Comment: Similar: *[How to change the color of an image in GIMP](http://superuser.com/questions/195087)*.

Answer (score 3):

As GIF files open in indexed mode by default, you might want to try converting the GIF into RGB mode (menu *Image* -> *Mode* -> *RGB*). Then change it using the Hue/Saturation/Value tool (menu *Colors* -> *Hue-Saturation*) and then converting it back into indexed before saving it.